# run PHP in phonegap

Tags: php, cordova

phonegap app has an `index.html` for its home page. My app only has `index.php`.
`index.php` contains

```
<?php
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        echo 'test';
    </body>
</html>
?>
```

I've read all over forums that phonegap does not support php and you have to use `Ajax`.

What i want is simply for my app to print `test` on android. Can anybody show me how to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest searching for some ajax tutorials. There are... many.

Answer (score 1):

**Currently it is not possible to use PHP in PhoneGap\Cordova**

If you want to display a simple text in your application, you can use plain HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

or JavaScript and libraries like jQuery that could generate some things, but if you want to view things from the outside, for example from a server that returns some data, you need to use AJAX

Comment: I have this in index.html : `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
            })
    });
</script>` But it does not work

Comment: its on my computer in the www folder. How else should the url be?

Comment: you have to put the index.php on a server and then use the url to the server